# Validar input type="number" >= 1 com Angular

Tags: angular

Estou tentando fazer uma validação para que o valor do meu input type="number" seje >= 1. Mas ja tentei varias coisas e nenhuma deu certo. estou tentando agora usar ng-pattern. Mas tem uma brecha. Se eu digitar 0 ele invalida, mas se eu digitar 01 ele valida!

```
<div ng-if="validaQtdPromotores(cadastro.cargo)" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : formCadastro.qtdPormotores.$invalid && !formCadastro.qtdPormotores.$pristine }">
   <input type="number" name="qtdPormotores" ng-model="cadastro.qtdPormotores" ng-pattern="/[1-9]/"  placeholder="Quantos promotores coordena?" required />
   <p ng-show="formCadastro.qtdPormotores.$invalid && !formCadastro.qtdPormotores.$pristine">Entre com um número válido.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: 01 é maior ou igual a 1, você não quer aceitar nenhum caractere 0?

Comment: A ideia é q o número não possa começar com zero. Ex: '0112'. Sendo assim, pode começar com qualquer número de 1-9 e ter zeros depois!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode modificar o seu pattern para:

```
/^[1-9][0-9]*$/
```

não irá permitir números que iniciem em 0

Comment: O angular n aceitou essa expressão: "SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[1-9]+*$/: Nothing to repeat"

Comment: corrigido, passou um * depois do +

Comment: É quase isso, mas essa inválida 10, 20, 30.. ou seja, qualquer número q tenha zero. A ideia é só invalidar o "0". Qualquer numero maior q zero tem q ser válido!

Comment: Ok, a pergunda não esta clara, atualizei o regex

Comment: Isso mesmo! funcionou agora! :D tentei quase isso tb! mas quando eu coloquei eu usei um assim /^[1-9]+[0-9]*$/ e ai deu erro! de qualquer forma valeu pelo ajuda! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Acho melhor você usar o atributo min=1 no input:
`<input type="number" min="1" name="qtdPormotores" ng-model="cadastro.qtdPormotores" placeholder="Quantos promotores coordena?" required />`

Comment: Oi @Flavio Misawa. usando a tag min="1" ele me retorna o msm problema do pattern q estou usando. se digito 0 invalida, mas se digito 01 valida!